# How to Delete Specific Cells in a User Specified Row

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for help to delete specific cells in a row that is specified by the user (`activecell.row`). My code inserts a line below the currently selected row. I would also like to delete a couple of the cells in that row without deleting the entire row and all of the formulas.

```
Sub AddNewLine()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim myVal As Integer

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    
    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    With ws
        '~~> Set your range
        Set rng = .Rows(ActiveCell.Row)

        '~~> Copy the range
        rng.Copy

        '~~> Insert the range
        rng.Offset(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
   
        'I would like to delete the values in these cells:
            Range("G.25").ClearContents
            Range("I25").ClearContents
            Range("J25").ClearContents
            Range("K25").ClearContents

    End With
       
    ActiveSheet.Protect
    
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [offtopic](This style of coding looks familiar :P)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub AddNewLine()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim myVal As Integer

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    
    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    With ws
        '~~> Set your range
        Set rng = .Rows(ActiveCell.Row)

        '~~> Copy the range
        rng.Copy

        '~~> Insert the range
        rng.Offset(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
   
        'I would like to delete the values in these cells:
        rng.Offset(1).Columns("G").ClearContents
        rng.Offset(1).Columns("I:K").ClearContents

    End With
       
    ActiveSheet.Protect
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub AddNewLine()
    Dim rng As Range
    
    With ActiveSheet
        .Unprotect
    
        '~~> Set your range
        Set rng = ActiveCell.EntireRow
        
        '~~> Copy the range
        rng.Copy
        
        '~~> Insert the range
        rng.Offset(1).Insert
        
        'I would like to delete the values in these cells:
        Intersect(.Range("G:G, I:K"), rng).ClearContents
    
        .Protect
    End With
End Sub
```